# How to combine two variables in PHP files()

Tags: php, file, variables

This is my script:

```
$t = file ('../../../../t.txt');
echo $t[1];
```

So I want to give "../../../../" a variable like **$path**. The issue is, to **combine this in a php string** or a right code.

**Example:**

```
$path = '../../../../';

$t = file ('($path)t.txt');
echo $t[1];
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Can someone write me how to do this right?

Comment: Learn how to use [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.` to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$path = '../../../../';

$t = file ($path . 't.txt');
echo $t[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$path = '../../../../';

$t = file($path.'t.txt');
echo $t[1];
```